# dynamically intitialize iset<t>

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

on constructing the class, i want to dynamically intialize all the ISet with HashSet,

Below is how I achieved it for for IList with List

```
var properties = GetType()
                .GetProperties()
                .Where(x => x.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
                            x.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>))
                .ToList();

            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                // get T type of ISet
                if (property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().Length > 1) continue;
                var listElemType = property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                if (listElemType == null) continue;

                // create hashedset
                var constructorInfo = typeof(List<>)
                    .MakeGenericType(listElemType)
                    .GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);

                //construct object
                if (constructorInfo == null) continue;
                var listInstance = (IList)constructorInfo.Invoke(null);
                property.SetValue(this, listInstance);
            }
```

but if I try the same thing for ISet, it does not work :(

```
        var properties = GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .Where(x => x.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
                        x.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ISet<>))
            .ToList();

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            // get T type of ISet
            if (property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().Length > 1) continue;
            var listElemType = property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            if (listElemType == null) continue;

            // create hashedset
            var constructorInfo = typeof(HashSet<>)
                .MakeGenericType(listElemType)
                .GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);

            //construct object
            if (constructorInfo == null) continue;
    //============== HERE IS THE PROBLEM ============
           // var listInstance = (ISet)constructorInfo.Invoke(null);
           // property.SetValue(this, listInstance);
        }
```

there is no ISet like for IList.. how to achieve it in this case??

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Why are you casting `listInstance` why not just leave it `object`?

Comment: @leppie his problem is there is no non-generic `ISet` interface so he does not know what to cast `listInstance` to.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain yes leaving it as object does the job.. no need of casting ... thanks for the quick answer

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Good spot :D

Comment: @ScottChamberlain would you like to put it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PropertyInfo.SetValue` requires `object`, so you don't have to cast result of `constructorInfo.Invoke(null)`:

```
var listInstance = constructorInfo.Invoke(null);
property.SetValue(this, listInstance);
```